# Проблема отрисовки поворота 3д модели через кватернион или не правильное создание физической сферы

Tags: c++, opengl

Всем привет, у меня проблема с отрисовкой поворота или не правильное создание физической сферы. Я с созданием сферы уверен полностью, но не исключаю что там может быть ошибка.
Вот код создания сферы:

```
void setSphere(btDynamicsWorld* world, vector<btRigidBody*> bodies, btVector3 pos, float rad)
{
    // это нужно чтобы нельзя было пересоздать объект если он уже создан
    if (this->type == 0)
    {
        this->type = SPHERE_TYPE;
        this->radius = rad;

        btTransform transform;
        transform.setIdentity();
        transform.setOrigin(pos);
                
        btSphereShape* sphere = new btSphereShape(rad);

        btVector3 inertia(0, 0, 0);
        if (this->mass != 0.0)
            sphere->calculateLocalInertia(this->mass, inertia);

        btMotionState* motion = new btDefaultMotionState(transform);
        btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo info(this->mass, motion, sphere, inertia);
                
        this->body = new btRigidBody(info);

        world->addRigidBody(this->body);
        bodies.push_back(this->body);
    }
}
```

Вот код где я рисую 3д модель:

```
void draw(Program program, GLuint texture)
{
    // get btTransform data
    btTransform transform;
    body->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(transform);

    // set varibles
    glm::mat4 translate, rotate, scaling, matModel;
    translate = rotate = scaling = matModel = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    
    // scale
    scaling = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), scale);
    if (type == SPHERE_TYPE)
        scaling = glm::scale(scaling, glm::vec3(radius));
    else if (type == CYLINDER_TYPE)
    {
        btVector3 extent = ((btCylinderShape*)body->getCollisionShape())->getHalfExtentsWithMargin();
        scaling = glm::scale(scaling, glm::vec3(extent.x(), extent.x(), extent.y()));
    }
    else if (type == CONE_TYPE)
    {
        float h = ((btConeShape*)body->getCollisionShape())->getHeight();
        scaling = glm::scale(scaling, glm::vec3(1, h / 2.0, 1));
    }
    else if (type == PLANE_STATIC_TYPE && scale == glm::vec3(1.0f))
        scaling = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(100.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f));

    // get quaternion
    btQuaternion rotation = transform.getRotation();
    // get position
    btVector3 btPos = transform.getOrigin();
    // rotate and translate
    if (rotation.getAngle() > 0.0)
    {
        rotate = glm::mat4_cast(engine::math::bulletToGlm(rotation));
        translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(btPos.x(), btPos.y() + rotation.getY(), btPos.z()));
    }
    else
        translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(btPos.x(), btPos.y(), btPos.z()));

    // get final 3d model matrix
    matModel = translate * rotate * scaling;

    // renderer
    program.setMat4("model", matModel);
    model->Draw(program, texture);
}
```

Мне кажется что проблема вот здесь:

```
if (rotation.getAngle() > 0.0)
{
    rotate = glm::mat4_cast(engine::math::bulletToGlm(rotation)); // <-- проблема должна быть в этой строке
    translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(btPos.x(), btPos.y() + rotation.getY(), btPos.z()));
}
else
    translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(btPos.x(), btPos.y(), btPos.z()));
```

Вот картинка вращения, извините за качество
[image: Вот так вращается 2 сфера]

И ещё, у меня 2 сферы. Одна вращается правильно, а другая ( которая на картинке ) вращается странно.
Вот код создания сфер:

```
//                 3д модель    вес    изменение размера 3д модели
PhysicBody sphere(&sphereModel, 10.0f, glm::vec3(0.036f));
//                 мир           физ. тела    позиция                радиус     
sphere.setSphere(engine.world, engine.bodies, btVector3(5.2, 20, 5), 2.0f);
engine.physicBodies.push_back(sphere);

PhysicBody sphere2(&sphereModel, 150.0f, glm::vec3(0.036001f));
sphere2.setSphere(engine.world, engine.bodies, btVector3(5.6, 160, 5.1), 1.0f);
engine.physicBodies.push_back(sphere2);
```

Comment: Как выглядит проблема?

Comment: Отредактировал.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл и понял проблему. Вопрос решён.
Вот исправленный код:

```
// rotate
btQuaternion rotation = transform.getRotation();
rotation.normalize();
if (rotation.getAngle() > 0.0)
{
    glm::quat q = glm::normalize(engine::math::bulletToGlm(rotation));
    rotate = glm::mat4(1.0f) * glm::mat4_cast(q);
}
```

Ошибка была в отсуствии нормализации

Comment: Как именно решён? Как понять другим посетителям с такой же проблемой, что делать? Отредактируйте ответ, добавьте решение вопроса.